# How to add another project as dependency in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring MVC 3.1 project. We have two project (both projects are in same workspace):

1. Core_Project - contains all the model and DB services etc.
2. WebApp_Project - contains controllers, views, web.xml etc.

`WebApp_Project` need jar/maven of `Core_Project` so we need to build the jar of Core_project and add jar using `Install or deploy an artifact to a maven repo` option in STS. Any small change in `Core_Project` need to repeat all this steps.

I tried adding Dependency using artifact details of `Core_project` in this way I need not to make jar and deploy into .m2 again and again.

But when I run my project I got `HTTP Status 404 -` error page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the location - WEB_PROJECT folder > target > yourfile.war > WEB-INF > lib. Lib folder should contain your jar file.

If your file is present there, your dependency is added to your WEB project. Then you will need to check your web project for 404 error.

If your jar file is not present in lib project, something is going wrong with your method of adding dependency.